# Copy a cell unless it contains the same value as a previous cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formulas

On one worksheet I have 4 cells (e.g., A1 through A4) that can each contain one of a handful of text options (e.g., red, blue, green, or yellow). So on one worksheet these four cells may be filled in as: A1=Red, A2=Green, A3=Red, A4=Red.

On a second worksheet, I want to fill in a single cell with the types of color chosen for those four cells. In the given example, this cell on the second worksheet would read "Red/Green."

I'm looking for a formula I can put into the cell on the second sheet that will check the four cells and pull only one of each that contains a unique text. Is there a formula that would, for example, copy A1, then copy A2 only if it is different from A1, then copy A3 only if it is different from both A1 and A2, then copy A4 only if it is different from A1, A2, and A3?

I hope that made sense. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Are you looking for a VBA macro? I think you could do that with a decent `If()` statement.  In sheet2, cell A2, something like `=If(sheet1!A2<>sheet1!A1,Sheet1!A2,"")` and drag down?  (For the parts you need multiple matches, just use `And()`:  `if(And(sheet1!A3<>Sheet1!A2,sheet1!A3<>sheet1!A1),sheet1!A3,"")`

Comment: I do not believe that there is a formula that will do what you want.  Using an advanced filter or a vba macro.  The easiest would be an advanced filter.  A quick search will give you results on how to use them.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to produce a string containing the list of distinct colors.  You should clarify that though.

Comment: I got something to work! It's...very clunky and really highlights how little I understand what I'm doing, but it relies heavily on your work, BruceWayne, so thank you! I ended up with:

=CONCATENATE(ZTY!C27, "/", IF(ZTY!G27<>ZTY!C27,ZTY!G27,""), "/", IF(AND(ZTY!C34<>ZTY!G27,ZTY!C34<>ZTY!C27),ZTY!C34,""))&CONCATENATE("/", IF(AND(ZTY!G34<>ZTY!C34,ZTY!G34<>ZTY!G27,ZTY!G34<>ZTY!C27),ZTY!G34,""))

I had to throw a second concatenate in there because it couldn't handle all my arguments...

Answer (score 1):

You can produce a distinct list with this formula. But it cannot be entered into the first row of the second sheet. Row two is fine:

```
=IFERROR(""&INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$999,MATCH(,INDEX(COUNTIF($a$1:a3,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$999),,),)),"")
```

Notice the lowercase characters of "a". There are two of them. Change those to whichever column you are using for the distinct list on the second sheet.

Additionally, you can change the 999's to scan as many rows from the first sheet as you need.